# Django 1.3: Can't access static files after trun off DEBUG

Tags: django

This is very very weird.

On my dev machine, everything seems fine when I set DEBUG=True, but If I turn it off, it then breaks.

I can see the requested URLs are exactly same. What are the possible reasons for this?

```
 In url

+ static("static", document_root= STATIC_ROOT )
```

The STATIC_ROOT is the absolute path to static folder, it's all right, cost it works when debug is turned on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From Django docs regarding [serving static files in development](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/howto/static-files/#serving-static-files-in-development):

> This will only work if DEBUG is True.
>
> That's because this view is grossly
>   inefficient and probably insecure.
>   This is only intended for local
>   development, and should never be used
>   in production.

In short, if you are using devserver and `DEBUG` is `False`, static files won't be served.

Comment: +1 Also, add static file serving only [if DEBUG is true](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.2/howto/static-files/#limiting-use-to-debug-true) else use proper web server.

Answer (score 1):

While I fixed this by replace that url config by

url(r'^static/(?P.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', { 'document_root': STATIC_ROOT }),

But I want to know why?